# Haskell , generating values for truth table

Tags: haskell

How can you generate the table truth values for an input of symbols?

```
Input : ["A", "B"]

Output: [("A", True), ("B", False)], [("A", True), ("B", True)],
        [("A", False), ("B", True)], [("A", False), ("B", False)]
```

In this exact format.

Comment: Could you also provide output sample for `["A", "B", "C"]` input?

Comment: I guess this is homework so what have you tried? - BTW: I think you want the first pair to be 2xFalse instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way:

### list comprehensions

let's give the symbols a name:

```
symbols :: [String]
symbols = ["A", "B"]
```

start by assigning all combinations of *one* symbol with the truth-values:

```
truth :: String -> [(String, Bool)]
truth s = [ (s,b) | b <- [True, False] ]
```

then you only have to calculate the cross-product of all those:

```
truths :: [String] -> [[(String,Bool)]]
truths [] = [[]]
truths (s:ss) = [ t:ts | t <- truth s, ts <- truths ss ]
```

which yields:

```
> truths symbols

[ [("A",True),("B",True)]
, [("A",True),("B",False)]
, [("A",False),("B",True)]
,[("A",False),("B",False)] ]
```

which is what you wanted (aside from reorderings ... you should be able to figure those out)

---

#### remarks/exercise:

- try to figure out how to get the order you want (aside from the strange flip you did in the very first pairs)
- there are predefined functions for this (cross-product) - try to find it
- you can generalize this quite a bit (no need for `String` or even `Bool`) - try to work it out for at least `[String] -> [a]`
- you can do this also with the `do` notation - try to figure it out
- there is yet another way of doing this with `concatMap` - try to figure it out!